# Is one projection which preserves norm is identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Given an orthogonal projection $\mathcal{P}$: $\mathbf{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{S}\text{ is one subspace of  } \mathbf{R}^{n}$. And let $||\cdot||_2$ denote $l_2$ norm. Then for one vector $v\in \mathbf{R}^{n}$, if $||\mathcal{P}(v)||_2=||v||_2$, can we conclude that: $v\in \mathcal{S}$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: No. Try $P(v)=-v$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I will rewrite the problem in another way.

Comment: If $\mathcal{P}$ is just a projection (not necessarily orthogonal) then we can NOT conclude that $v\in \mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{S}= \{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^2 : y=0\}$. Let $\mathcal{P}$: $\mathbf{R}^2\rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ defined by $\mathcal{P}(x,y)=(x+y,0)$. Then we have that $\mathcal{P}$ is linear and $\mathcal{P}\circ \mathcal{P}= \mathcal{P}$, so $\mathcal{P}$ is a projection. However, $\mathcal{P}$ is NOT orthogonal and if we take $v=(0,1)$  we have $\mathcal{P}(v)=(1,0)$ and so $||\mathcal{P}(v)||_2=||v||_2$, but $v\notin \mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thank you guys. I think the orthogonality is necessary. I just set the space as a Hilbert space, thus it is nature to consider one orthogonal projection. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: No, it is not "natural to consider one orthogonal projection". Hilbert spaces have projections that are not orthogonal.   In fact, the examples given by me and @user190080 are in  $\mathbf{R}^2$, which is a Hilbert space.  

You can not assume a projection is orthogonal just because it is in Hilbert space.

Comment: It is worth to note that orthogonal projections are very "rare" among the projections in Hilbert spaces. The example below illustrates this point.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{S}= \{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^2 : y=0\}$. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a linear map from $\mathbf{R}^2$ to $\mathcal{S}$. Then we have that $\mathcal{P}$ is a projection if and only if there is $b\in \mathbf{R}$ such that, for all $(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^2$,  $\mathcal{P}(x,y)=(x+by,0)$. In fact, we have a bijection between  $\mathbf{R}$ and the set of projections from $\mathbf{R}^2$ to $\mathcal{S}$. However, $\mathcal{P}$ is ortogonal if and only if $b=0$. So orthogonal projections are as "rare" among projections from $\mathbf{R}^2$ onto $\mathcal{S}$ as  $0$ is "rare" in $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: well, @Ramiro has a point, there are of course not only orthogonal projections in Hilbert spaces, on the other hand, it is somehow natural to consider orthogonal projections in certain settings, e.g. you have a separable Hilbert space like $\mathbb{R}^n$ and an orthonormal basis $(e_i)$, then you can simply express the orthogonal projection on some subspace generated by some $(e_j)$ by the sum  $\sum<e_j,a_i>e_j$ which comes very handy

Comment: @user190080  When you and I answered the question, it is was about projections (in general). Then the question was updated under the explanation that it would be "natural"  to consider a projection in Hilbert space to be orthogonal. Then, I just tried to highlight that, although orthogonal projections are really VERY important and useful, we can not assume that projections in Hilbert spaces will "naturally" be orthogonal. Non-orthogonal projections in Hilbert spaces are NOT special pathological cases. In fact, most of the projections in Hilbert spaces are non-orthogonal.

Comment: @Ramiro I completely agree, a projection in a hilbert space is not a priori orthogonal  - although in a lot of use cases they are the only relevant one. With the  additional answer from aloizo  and your comments i think the problems regarding the question are sufficiently dealt with

Answer (score 2):

Ramiro is right in his comment when he says that

> if $\mathcal{P}$ is just a projection (not necessarily orthogonal)
>   then we can NOT conclude that $v\in \mathcal{S}$

for this to see, we construct a simple counterexample. We take as a projection
$$
\mathcal{P}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
operating on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and subspace generated by $$v=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$
so $\mathcal{S}=\operatorname{span}(v)$. Now we take 
$$
w=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}, ||w||_2=1
$$
but we also have 
$$
\mathcal{P}w=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}w=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\implies ||\mathcal{P}w||_2= ||w||_2=1
$$
but we have 
$$
w\text{ not an element of }\mathcal{S}=\operatorname{span}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

A *projection* is a map of the form $P^2=P$. Every projection splits $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the following way:

$$\mathbb{R}^n \cong \ker P\oplus \text{im } P,$$

which is easily seen from the fact that $x=(I-P)x+Px$.

An *orthogonal projection* is a projection for which $\ker P$ and $\text{im }P$ are orthogonal. Hence, if you are in an orthogonal projection,

$$\|P(v)\|=\|P(v_k+v_i)\|=\|P(v_k)+P(v_i)\|=\|P(v_i)\|=\|v_i\|.$$

Therefore, if $\|P(v)\|=\|v\|$, then $\|v\|=\|v_i\|$. Since $\|v\|=\|v_i\|+\|v_k\|$ (here we use the orthogonal assumption), then $\|v_k\|=0$, which implies $v=v_i$, and then that $v \in \text{im } P$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missed that $P$ is a projection. In that case it's correct. Let $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $S$. Let us complete it to an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k,v_{k+1},...,v_n\}$. We know $v=\sum_{j=1}^n<v,v_j>v_j$ and $P(v)=\sum_{j=1}^k<v,v_j>v_j$. Now $||v||_2^2=||\sum_{j=1}^n<v,v_j>v_j||_2^2=\sum_{j=1}^n|<v,v_j>|^2$ and $||P(v)||_2^2=||\sum_{j=1}^k<v,v_j>v_j||_2^2=\sum_{j=1}^k|<v,v_j>|^2$. With these represantations it is easy to see that $||P(v)||_2=||v||_2 \iff \forall j\in \{k+1,...,n\}$ $|<v,v_j>|=0 \iff \forall j\in \{k+1,...,n\}$ $<v,v_j>=0$ which implies $$v=\sum_{j=1}^n<v,v_j>v_j=\sum_{j=1}^k<v,v_j>v_j=P(v)$$

Comment: Sorry, but when you write $P(v)=\sum_{j=1}^k<v,v_j>v_j$, you are assuming that $P$ is an ORTHOGONAL projection.  However, we only know that $P$ is projection (not necessarily orthogonal).